# Cron php update/insert one sql table from another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, cron

I am not that good in php so I would appreciate your help.

I need to update or insert certain data from one mysql table to another mysql table same server!

Bought tables have same column and what I want is to update certain rows with prechosen mid!
Table:

```
|ID| |mid| |value1| |value2|
```

I did the part where php for update or insert to check if it exists but what I need it to do is to repeat the step pos each given

So what I need it to repeat this script for each mid I list to be done

```
mid1 = 66
mid2 = 78
mid3 = 24


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","User","Pass");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db(baza, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE mid='???' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$mid=$row['mid'];
$name=$row['value1'];
$alias=$row['value2'];
}

mysql_close($con);
?> 
<?php
$con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","user2","pass2");
if (!$con2)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db(baza2, $con2);


$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE mid='$mid' ";
$resulta = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($resulta) )
{

mysql_query("UPDATE table SET mid='$mid', name='$name', alias='$alias'");
mysql_close($con2);
echo "1 record added1";
}
else
{
$sql="INSERT INTO table (mid, name, alias)
VALUES
('$mid','$name','$alias')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con2))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con2);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i think mysql where in function is what u need....`SELECT * FROM table WHERE mid in('66,78,24') `.

Comment: Stop using mysql_ functions buddy. Move to mysqli_ instead (if you like the procedural way).  mysql_ is deprecated, so try to learn yourself the better way while you are learning. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Also take a look at mysql's `insert... select` functionality: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html. If you need to select something from one table just to insert it into the other. You might be better off omitting php in the first place..

Comment: - bipen thx
- Damien Overeem thanks for your proposal I will look into that but now I don’t have that much time!
 - bipen thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2 databases are on the same server, you can set-up your account to have access to both databases. If so, you can simple select the database in your queries on this way:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_database.my_table WHERE ..");
```

Your code will be..

```
$mid_array = array(66, 78, 24);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if(!$con) {
    die('could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db(baza, $con);

foreach($mid_array AS $mid) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE mid = '".$mid."'";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO baza2.table (mid, name, alias) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['alias']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '".$row['name']."', alias = '".$row['alias']."'");
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
```

You don't need a different query to check if the record with mid = .. already exists. You can simply handle this with the mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement which will do this for you in only 1 query!

Comment: ennovativemedia just to be on safe side before implementing your solution.
Baza1 is the database with all data and all mid-s are listed there I just need some of mid-s from that one to bi update/inserted in baza2
Also each table in bought databases have auto increment ID but because db1 has more mid-s than db2 they don’t correspond can that be a problem!
P.S.
Forgot to tell you thank you!

Comment: I don't see a direct problem. As you set the "mid" yourself in db2, if the "mid" alreaddy exists, it just updates the name and alias.

Comment: it works just need to add -- ) -- "SELECT * FROM table WHERE mid = '".$mid."'");

Comment: ennovativemedia are you still there?

Comment: Well I have e problem that one of the field is named show so if I delete that and every thigh after in insert AND update it works but if I put it back it don’t
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO baza2.table (mid, name, alias, show ,    value1) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['alias']."', '".$row['show']."', '".$row['value1']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '".$row['name']."', alias = '".$row['alias']." , show = '".$row['show']."' , value1 = '".$row['value1']."' ");

Comment: Query edited: mysql_query("INSERT INTO baza2.table (mid, name, alias, show , value1) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['alias']."', '".$row['show']."', '".$row['value1']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '".$row['name']."', alias = '".$row['alias']."' , show = '".$row['show']."' , value1 = '".$row['value1']."'"); You did forget a quote after updating alias

Comment: Sorry I mistyped here is the origina:

1. Not working:
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db2.s_properties_profiles (mid, name, alias, company, type, show) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['alias']."', '".$row['company']."', '".$row['type']."','".$row['show']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '".$row['name']."', alias = '".$row['alias']."', company = '".$row['company']."', type = '".$row['type']."', show = '".$row['show']."'");

Comment: 2. Working
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db2.s_properties_profiles (mid, name, alias, company, type) VALUES ('".$row['mid']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['alias']."', '".$row['company']."', '".$row['type']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '".$row['name']."', alias = '".$row['alias']."', company = '".$row['company']."', type = '".$row['type']."'");

Comment: try naming your field 'show' differently. I guess it's a reserved word in mysql, or place ` around it